# Retrieving AIC from a Holt-Winters model in R

Tags: r, holtwinters

I am relatively new to R (and any kind of programming in general) and I am trying to generate forecasting models. One of the methods I have been looking into is the Holt-Winters method, using the `HoltWinters` function from the {stats} package in R.

```
HW <- HoltWinters(DollarSales.ts, seasonal = "multiplicative")
checkresiduals(HW)
```

In doing so, I get what looks like a strong model with a good p-value for the Ljung-Box test. However, I have been unable to find the AIC for the model so that I can compare fit with other models such as ARIMA.

I have tried using the AIC() function but I am met with the error message:

Error in UseMethod("logLik") :
no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "HoltWinters"

Does anyone know a way around this?